Proof for least squares approximation problem given two points and a data set of length $n$
I have the following problem from my numerical methods class:
Given a data set $\{(x_i,y_i):i=1...n\}$ where $x_i$ are not all equal and $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i \neq 0$, prove that the only line that best approximates the data in the least squares sense is the line that passes through the points
$$
\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i,\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\right), 
\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i)²}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i},\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}\right)
$$
I have already developed the normal equation for this problem, $A^TAx=A^Tb$ where $A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&x_1 \\
1&x_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots\\
1& x_n
\end{pmatrix}$, and so
$$
A^TA=
\begin{pmatrix}
n&\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\\
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i & \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i)²
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
A^Tb = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^n y_i \\
\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Hence, we have that
$$
A^TAx=A^Tb
$$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
n&\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\\
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i & \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i)²
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_0\\
a_1
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^n y_i \\
\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Here lies my problem: I don't know how to solve this system. I've tried Gaussian elimination to triangulate the matrix but I've reached nowhere. I also tried to solve it by replacing one result from $a_0$ into $a_1$ but couldn't continue. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.
-L

It is a 2x2 linear system and keep in mind that all the coefficients in the matrix and rhs are given (depend just on the data). For such a small system, you can use Cramer's rule and get
$$
a_0 =\dfrac{\sum y_i \cdot \sum x_i^2 - \sum x_i y_i \cdot \sum x_i}{n \sum x_i^2 - (\sum x_i)^2}, \quad a_1 =\dfrac{n \cdot \sum x_i y_i - \sum x_i \cdot \sum y_i}{n \sum x_i^2 - (\sum x_i)^2}
$$
Now that you have the regression line, just plug in the two given points and check that they are actually on the line. For instance, for the first point, simplifying
$$
 \dfrac{\sum y_i \cdot \sum x_i^2 - \sum x_i y_i \cdot \sum x_i}{n \sum x_i^2 - (\sum x_i)^2} + \dfrac{n \cdot \sum x_i y_i - \sum x_i \cdot \sum y_i}{n \sum x_i^2 - (\sum x_i)^2} \cdot \frac 1n \sum x_i
$$
should give $\frac 1n \sum y_i$.

You need to compute the inverse of this 2 by 2 matrix.
$$\begin{bmatrix}a_0\\b_0\end{bmatrix}=\frac1{nS(x^2)-(S(x))^2}\begin{bmatrix}S(x^2)&-S(x)\\-S(x)&n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}S(y)\\S(xy)\end{bmatrix}=\frac1{nS(x^2)-(S(x))^2}\begin{bmatrix}S(x^2)S(y)-S(x)S(xy)\\nS(xy)-S(x)S(y)\end{bmatrix}
=\frac1{M(x^2)-(M(x))^2}\begin{bmatrix}M(x^2)M(y)-M(x)M(xy)\\M(xy)-M(x)M(y)\end{bmatrix}$$
Thus the line you want is
$$y'=x'\frac{M(xy)-M(x)M(y)}{M(x^2)-M^2(x)}+\frac{M(x^2)M(y)-M(x)M(xy)}{M(x^2)-M^2(x)}$$
If now $x'=M(x)$, then $y'$ must be
$$y'=\frac{M(x)M(xy)-M^2(x)M(y)+M(x^2)M(y)-M(x)M(xy)}{M(x^2)-M^2(x)}=M(y)$$
Showing your first point. As for the second if $x'=M(x^2)/M(x)$, then
$$y'=\frac{M(x^2)M(xy)-M(x)M(y)M(x^2)+M(x^2)M(x)M(y)-M^2(x)M(xy)}{M(x)(M(x^2)-M^2(x))}=\frac{M(xy)}{M(x)}$$
Concluding the second part.
PS: by $S(z)$, I mean $\sum_{j=1}^n z_j$ and by $M(z)$, I mean $S(z)/n$.

Do it like Einstein, if you can't remember a formula, deduce it.
I guess, by "in the least squares sense" you mean linear regression of model $y=mx+b$. But which distance of measured points to the resulting line do you square? i) vertical, ii) horizontal, or iii) orthogonal? Most probably i), thus the sum of squared distances is $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n (y_k - (mx_k +b))^2\:\Rightarrow min\tag{1}$
$(1)$ expanded: $\displaystyle m^2\sum_{k=1}^n\,x_{k}^2+2mb\sum_{k=1}^n\,x_{k}-2m\sum_{k=1}^n\,x_{k}y_{k}+nb^2-2b\sum_{k=1}^n\,y_{k}+\sum_{k=1}^n\,y_{k}^2\tag{2}$
Further on $\sum$ stands for $\sum_{k=1}^n$
To find $b$ derive $(2)$ to $b$: $\displaystyle 2\left(m\sum x_k+nb-\sum y_k\right)\tag{3}$
and set $(3)$ to $0$ and solve for $b$: $\displaystyle b=\frac{-m\sum x_k+\sum y_k}{n}\tag{4}$
or simplified: $b=\bar{y}-m\bar{x}$. Rearranged to $\bar{y}=m\bar{x}+b$ it's obvious (me think) that the first point is confirmed.
Now to the next one where the resulting line will pass. Substitute $b$ from $(4)$ in $(2)$: $\left(nm^2\sum x_k^2-2nm\sum x_k y_k+n\sum y_k^2-m^2\left(\sum x_k\right)^2+2m\sum x_k\cdot\sum y_k-\left(\sum y_k\right)^2\right)/n\tag{5}$
Derive $(5)$ to $m$: $\displaystyle\frac{2\left(nm\sum x_k^2-n\sum x_k y_{k}-m\left(\sum x_k\right)^2+\sum x_k\cdot\sum y_k\right)}{n}\tag{6}$
Set $(6)$ to $0$ and solve for $m$: $\displaystyle m=\frac{\sum x_k y_k-\sum x_k\cdot\sum y_k}{n\sum x_k^2-\left(\sum x_k\right)^2}\tag{7}$
Note: up to here I just applied the LS method.
The rest is simple algebra: $\displaystyle y=m\cdot\frac{\sum x_k^2}{\sum x_k}+b$ with $(4)$ and $(7)$ yields $$\frac{\sum x_k y_k}{\sum x_k}$$
qed.
